# Why my QR code generated in C# for an UWP application can`t be read only on ARM applications?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, arm

I have C# code that generates a QR code on UWP, using ZXing library. The QR code works well, but specifically on ARM computers, it is not readable. The image is generated but can't be read by the camera (any link open, the QR Code seems to be not completely formed). I tried to use QRCoder library too, and same thing occurred. Someone know some way to fix it?
Note: in debug mode, qr code works good in ARM, only in release it is not readable.
I tested it with 2 different ARM computers with different screen types, tried to generate different QR codes too.
Images attached.

My code for generate qr code:

```
        options.Hints.Add(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.H);

        BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter();
        writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
        writer.Options = options;

        BitMatrix input = writer.Encode(text);

        SoftwareBitmap bitmap = GetQRCodeBitmap(QrCodeSize, QrCodeSize, input);
        SoftwareBitmapSource imageSource = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
        await imageSource.SetBitmapAsync(bitmap);
        QRCodeImage = imageSource;
```

[QR Code readable image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp7EM.png)

[QR Code not readable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYtt0.png)

Comment: Not sure how to interpret your question: (A) the QR code created for the same data looks different when created on ARM than on x86 and the first one is not readable by some (which?) app. Or (B) reading the same QR code with an app works on x86, but does not work on ARM.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The QR code is readeble by smartphone camera and works good in any computer, but not in ARM. Same qr code (with same link), when generated on ARM computer, is not readable, looks damaged, maybe not completely processed. I tried a lot of possible solutions, but without success.
Note: if the qr code was generated on a computer not-arm, and we take a screenshot and use it on ARM, then it's readable, but not when it's generated on arm (both debug or release mode).

Comment: Ok. I'll put it on the description.

Comment: Please add the two QR code images to your question: the working one and the non-working one.

Comment: I pasted the readable qr code and i'm waiting arm load to generate a non-readable qr code. And sorry, i said it occurs both in debug and release modes, but just occurs in release mode, in debug qr code works good on ARM.

Comment: Both images (readable and not readable) attached.